# Where to find documentation of apache2-mod-xsendfile version 9.2?

Tags: apache

I have this version installed and I'm unable to correctly configure the module due to a lack of documentation. In particular the option XSendFilePath is not recognized:

Invalid command 'XSendFilePath', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

If I remove the XSendFilePath directive I get the error:
The given path was above the root path: xsendfile: unable to find file:

Comment: The online docs have detailed examples... https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Comment: @Ken: if I try the examples provided I get the error: Invalid command 'XSendFilePath', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Did you load the module in your httpd.conf file? `LoadModule xsendfile_module   modules/mod_xsendfile.so`

Comment: @Ken: I would say that the module has been loaded because the command 'XSendFile on' is recognized.